# How to assign a different key to each <li> according to this code in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Good morning,
I'm looking on StackOverflow how to assign a different key to each item I return. The problem is that even after trying different solutions, it doesn't work and I still get the same error. I explain myself a little better. My object returns different information depending on the users. Except when I try to use a key with uuidv4(), it doesn't work. Elements are duplicated and I don't know how to fix this problem.
Do you have a solution or a post on StackOverflow to fix this problem?

(Items will be changed on the back-end side in the future. For now I'm coding all this on the front-end side.)

```
    const userInLive = [
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconGotaga}`,
            username: 'Gotaga',
            game: 'Fortnite',
            countViewers: '14K'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconSardoche}`,
            username: 'Sardoche',
            game: 'League of Legends',
            countViewers: '15K'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon: `${IconSqueezie}`,
            username: 'Squeezie',
            game: 'Among Us',
            countViewers: '153k'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconWartek}`,
            username: 'WaRTeK',
            game: 'Call of Duty MW2',
            countViewers: '2k'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconAylan}`,
            username: 'Aylan',
            game: 'Just Chatting',
            countViewers: '150k'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconConflict}`,
            username: 'Conflict',
            game: 'HackTheBox',
            countViewers: '189k'
        },
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            icon:`${IconGogo}`,
            username: 'Gogo Méchant Loup',
            game: 'Plato',
            countViewers: '5K'
        },
    ]
...

    return (
        <aside className="recommanded-container" id="aside-container" style={
            theme ?{backgroundColor: '#1F1F23'} : {backgroundColor: '#EFEFF1'}}>
            <div className="recommanded-container__top">
                <h2 id="recommanded-text" style={theme ? {color: 'white'}: {color: 'black'}}>Chaînes recommandées</h2>
                <ul id="list-icon">
                    <li id="icon-reduce">
                        <img src={theme ? LightLeave : DarkLeave } alt="reduce" id="reduce-recommanded" className={theme ? 'reduce-recommanded' : 'dark-reduce-recommanded'}/>
                    </li>
                    <li id="icon-inlive">
                        <img src={theme ? LightVideo : DarkVideo} alt="inlive" id="inlive-recommanded"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="usersInLive">
                {userInLive.map((element) => {
                    return(
                        <div id="user" className={theme ? "userDark" : "userLight"}>
                            <img src={element.icon} alt="user_icon" id="current_user_icon"/>
                            <div id="user_global_informations" style={isReduce ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'visible'}}>
                                <ul className="live_user_informations">
                                    <li id="username_information" key={element.id}>
                                        <p style={theme ? { color: 'white'}:{color:'black'
                                        }}>{element.username}</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="game_information" key={element.id}>
                                        {element.game}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul className="live_current_informations">
                                    <li id="inLiveDot">
                                        <span id="isInLive"/>
                                    </li>
                                    <li key={element.id}>
                                        <p style={theme ? { color: 'white'}:{color:'black'
                                        }}>{element.countViewers}</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </aside>
    )
```

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Hello. Can you please mention what other options did you explored?

Comment: Hi, I tried with "index", uuidv4() and that's all

Comment: You can look into Nano ID, which is a nano-sized unique string ID generator for JavaScript.
Or you can simply use Date somehow to make a unique key for the same.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Using `uuidv4()` when your data is inside your component is not recommended. When your component updates your `userInLive` will get a new reference causing it to create new ids for all the items. This way your rendered items will get new `keys` and probably will render even if its not needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **key** when iterating or building list item with array in Reactjs to ensure unique rendering.

**Example**

```
{
  userInLive.map((element, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={element.id} id="user" className={theme ? "userDark" : "userLight"}>
        
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. So I don't have to define a key on an LI tag, I can do it on any tag?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a unique key using Date Object: new Date().valueOf();

or, you can also look into - Nano ID, which is a nano-sized unique string ID generator for JavaScript.

Update:
check this for more - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid

Answer (score 1):

If you will use `uuidv4()` for unique id generation the problem with that approach is that it will change these ids on every time (on userInLive array change or component re-render)  that will defeat the purpose of using unique key in the list.
So it would be good if you use [database id](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) if userInLive is coming from a database or if you are making userInLive array on react client then you can add these ids as unique number or any other string field (ex- email or user name) that does not change.